# How to navigate in electron without opening new windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application, desktop

I want to move between html pages in the same window without opening a new window on each navigation how do I do that in electron

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious answer would be to load a different HTML file on a certain event that you trigger (most likely using ipc)

```
ipcMain.on("some-event",(event)=>{
 /** */
let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow(); // get active window
win.loadFile("2nd html.html"); // refresh html file
/** OR */ 
win.loadURL("remote URL.html") // refresh html file from a remote link

win.reload() // if necessary
})
```

make sure you pass any data required using ipcRenderer and ipcMain before you load your file.